# GoldMine 5.7 - How to import email templates?

Tags: templates, goldmine

I am helping a small business upgrade their GoldMine software. They have been using GoldMine and have a bunch of email templates on their server, located in G:\EmailTemplates.

I don't see any options to import existing templates. I can only see how to create new templates.

Can you help me import existing email templates?

Comment: I am not working on this project any longer and never received an answer. I am closing this question.